# Axios post in React front end leading to error when posting to MailerLite

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have the following component:

```
const WaitingListComponent = () => {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  const onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    axios.post("/api/waiting-list/addToList", {
      email: email
    })
    }

  return (
    <form className="waiting-list-component-container" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h4 className="waiting-list-component-heading">Join our waiting list to get early access</h4>
      <p className="waiting-list-component-paragraph">Join our waiting list to get exclusive early access to our platform when we're ready to launch.</p>
      <input className="waiting-list-component-input" name="email" type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="janedoe@email.com" />
      <GeneralButton type="submit" text="Get access" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

This Axios request is getting posted via the following function:

```
const MailerLite = require('mailerlite-api-v2-node').default;

const mailerLite = MailerLite(process.env.MAILER_API);

module.exports = (req, res) => {

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  const email = req.body.email;

  mailerLite.addSubscriberToGroup(process.env.MAILER_GROUP, email)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully sent new subscriber to MailerLite.");
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("There was an error.");
    console.log(err);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false }));
  });

};
```

This is a post to a website called 'MailerLite'.

Their documentation is here: https://developers.mailerlite.com/docs/getting-started-with-mailerlite-api
And the package I'm using to post via node is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailerlite-api-v2-node#addsubscribertogroupgroupid-subscriber

I'm attempting to use the 'addSubscriberToGroup' function to add a new subscriber to my group.

However, despite the Axios post successfully going through - as shown in the error message - there is an error being generated each time.

I don't want to post the full error because it's lengthy and it contains the API key, but the final two lines indicate it's an Axios error:

> isAxiosError: true

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here?

If you need more info, or have any specific questions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you need to send email as an object. You could do it like this: `addSubscriberToGroup('id', { email: email })`